# Switching Circuit for four led's and four switches

Tags: led, control, switching

i need a circuit for my project which has 4 led and their corresponding 4 switches. Now when i press switch of first led then only first led should glow. After that when i press switch of second led then second led should glow and at the same time first led should become off. Similarly when i press switch of third led then third led should glow and second led should become off automatically. Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: [Many ideas here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=cd4017+led+driver&num=100&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtx_GCxarPAhWJNpQKHYfiAjYQsAQIGw&biw=1680&bih=920).

Comment: What happens to 1st LED if its button is held but the third (or fourth) button is also held? Then what should happen if the third switch is activated and then the 1st switch is activated - are you expecting that the earlier LED should extinguish in preference to the subsequent button press? Also, when you press a button and an LED glows are you expecting that LED to remain glowing when you release the button? In other words your question is under-constrained so go back and think about every action and draw a truth table and please do this "as soon as possible". 1 hour gone!

Comment: @RAJAT: "_Please help me as soon as possible._" I think you misunderstand our relationship. If you ask a good question that is of interest to some of the readers then we'll answer when it suits us.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as EE.SE is not a free design service.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Interlocking push-button switches. Pressing one button cams the holding bar sideways to release the other buttons.*

You will find these parts by searching for "interlocking push-button switches".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fojv3z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A one of four circuit using mechanically interlocked push buttons switches.*

This circuit avoids any electronics other than the resistors and LEDs themselves.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Per LED provide a 'latch' that is set by its own pushbutton but reset by a common reset line. Each latch drives the reset line when it is activated.

**Action:**

Pressing switch N lights LED N and extinguishes all other LEDs.

**Description:**

The circuit shows one stage.
2 to many stages can be provided.
The V+ line and the "Reset" line are shared by all stages.

IC1a ICab MUST be Schmitt trigger action gates. eg 74C14, 74HC14 etc.

IC1a + IC1b form a bistable latch. R1 couples output to imput so the gates are either stably high or stably low.

Pressing SW1 sets IC1b high, LED lights, Latch is latched on.
IC1a out is low. Diode D1 couples this low to the common reset line.
R2 couples the rest line to the latch input. If SW1 is pressed R2-low will be overridden . If Sw1 is NOT pressed the latch will be reset by IC1A low via R2

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTsUw2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another way is use 4017 Johnson counter with inexpensive momentary push buttons (SPST-NO) using gates and FF to reset and scan switches if any switch is depressed and output stops which is ANDed with switch and numbered output from 0 to 3 or 0 to 9 possible and then disable clock with SR FF.   It would stop on the lowest numbered switch pressed first.

If interest is shown by sufficient votes, I can draw it out